# View content gets out off bounds in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I need to align two `TextViews` in a row with dynamic content and therefore width. `ConstraintLayout` works good until text starts wrapping into multiple lines. The left view shifts to the left (goes beyond the left border) on the width of the second view. How to avoid that? Is it some kind of bug or I am forgetting smth using `ConstraintLayout` incorrectly?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="textView2 Lorem ipsum "
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="textView1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Shifted view image:**

[image: Shifted image]

Comment: I've also had trouble controlling width of TextViews that word-wrap.  I was dealing with translation strings.  I was lucky enough that I could shorten the translations to prevent word wrapping.  If that hadn't worked, my next approach I would have tried is assigning fixed width or investigating if I could assign a maximum width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf` to `layout_constraintStart_toStartOf` and `layout_constraintRight_toRightOf` to `layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf` and you will get something that looks like the following:

[image]

This assumes `ConstraintLayout` version 1.1.0 although it may not matter.

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you could have just tied it to a guideline that starts from the end of the first textview. both text views could have had there ends tied to a guideline.

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/glMiddle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="56dp" />
```

tie tv1 end to this and tie tv2's start to this